# How to add fail to ant macrodef

Tags: ant, macrodef

I created a macro to search for a file in a number of directories. That part is working.

Now I'm trying to add fail to the macro if no file is found but this gives me an error
`macrodef doesn't support the nested "fail" element.`

Is there a way to achieve this ?

```
<macrodef name="searchfile">
    <attribute name="file" />
    <attribute name="path" default="${custom.buildconfig},${wst.basedir}" />
    <attribute name="name" />
    <attribute name="verbose" default="false" />
    <sequential>
        <first id="@{name}">
            <multirootfileset basedirs="@{path}" includes="@{file}" erroronmissingdir="false" />
        </first>
        <property name="@{name}" value="${toString:@{name}}" />
        <echo>property @{name} ${@{name}}</echo>
    </sequential>
    <fail message="${file}was not found in ${custom.buildconfig},${wst.basedir}">
        <condition>
            <equals arg1="${@{name}" arg2=""/>
        </condition>
    </fail>
</macrodef>
```

Comment: Put the fail task in the sequential.  I think you have some unmatched braces too.

Answer (score 1):

Credits to martin clayton for his comment, moving fail in the sequential fixes the issue.

```
   <macrodef name="searchfile">
        <attribute name="file" />
        <attribute name="path" default="${custom.buildconfig},${wst.basedir}" />
        <attribute name="name" />
        <attribute name="verbose" default="false" />
        <sequential>
            <first id="@{name}">
                <multirootfileset basedirs="@{path}" includes="@{file}" erroronmissingdir="false" />
            </first>
            <property name="@{name}" value="${toString:@{name}}" />
            <echo>property @{name}=${toString:@{name}}</echo>
            <fail message="@{file} was not found in ${custom.buildconfig},${wst.basedir}, customdir=${customdir}">
                <condition>
                    <equals arg1="${toString:@{name}}" arg2=""/>
                </condition>
            </fail>
        </sequential>
    </macrodef>
```